# Prevent PHP DomDocument loadHTML() from removing characters due to entity encoding

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

I am using PHP DomDocument to parse my code so anything in a `<code>` block gets `htmlspecialchars()` encoded. However, the `loadHTML()` method is doing some weird things to my string. On a tag like this `<Tag *:35>`, it removes everything after the asterisk, along with lowercasing the first letter. If I do `htmlspecialchars()`, right before `loadHTML()`, then it prevent this from happening, but then entity encodes my ENTIRE page which is not my intended result. I simply want it to do this to everything my code tag, which it is already doing pretty much perfectly. It's just this one weird behavior.

Comment: Then what is `<Tag *:35>`?

Comment: It's apache config code. i just used "tag" merely for the example, but it's not that relevent

Comment: It can't be like that. As a literal text it should be escaped otherwise it is interpreted as part of HTML document which should be valid.

Comment: Yes, it should be escaped. But it shouldn't be removing characters and lowercasing some too

Comment: Well, an Apache config file is definitely **not** [valid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html). So, not sure why you're trying to parse something that **isn't** HTML with an HTML parser.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I was trying to add html entities to anything in a code block **NOT** escape it. DomDoc obviously does this by default, but I was trying to prevent this behavior. Anyway, I ended up just switching everything to markdown instead. Better solution for this task. Would still be interested in a DomDoc solution for poops and giggles